# ASP.NET data bind two-way, bi-directional from code behind

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

so for two-way (bi-directional) databinding in ASP, we do this...

```
<asp:textbox id="txtField" runat="server" 
    text='<%# Bind("SomeField") %>'>
</asp:textbox>
```

SomeField is located on the DataSource of the DetailsView that serves as the container for the textbox.

Alternatively I could do this from code-behind (using the textbox's OnDataBinding event):

```
protected void SomeField_OnDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  ((TextBox)sender).Text = Eval("SomeField").ToString();
}
```

However, EVAL is read-only...how can I specify Bind (two-way) from code-behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to find a work-around for my "edge-case".

I am using LLBLGen subtypes and therefore need to switch the datasource of the detailsview based on a radiobutton filter selected by the user.

I tried to bind to the sub type field "declaratively" in ASP using <%# Bind(...
This did not work.

I had to resolve to a code-behind "hack" where I conditionally display the controls in the detailsview using details_view pre-render method.

For each field I then conditionally setup it's one-way (read-only) bind in OnDataBinding...

```
e.g. ((TextBox)sender).Text = Eval("FilePrefix").ToString();
```

Finaly to get the data to push into the datasource, I hack the DetailsView OnItemInserting/Updating events (conditionally as well)...

```
e.Values["FilePrefix"] = txtFilePrefix.Text;
```

I feel so dirty after this hack I think I need a shower...

I still hope someone can provide a cleaner approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out this page on MSDN, [Walkthrough: Editing and Inserting Data in Web Pages with the DetailsView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdba1d59(v=VS.80).aspx) ?

Comment: The Eval (one-way) method works. I want Bind (two-way) to work.
Also I am not using a repeater, but a detailsview.

Comment: I think I'm probably misunderstanding your problem. There's really no such thing as two-way binding. You can set the value of the control in either the .aspx page or in the code-behind. To get the value back (i.e. the user input), you have to access the Text property of the control. What is "SomeField". A property on the code-behind class?

Comment: Somefield if a table column located on the DataSource of the DetailsView that serves as the container for the textbox.

I am interested in having the textbox push data into database. Thats why I need to use Bind. It's simple really. Except it does not seem to be easily made available from codebehind. Using <%# Bind( yes, but not as easy in code...