# How to transform a custom CheckBoxList into an equivalent GridView?

Tags: c#, data-binding, gridview, webforms, checkboxlist

I have this custom CheckBoxList:

```
<CustomCheckBoxList runat="server" ID="ItemsCBL" DataSourceID="ItemsData"
    DataTextField="datacolumn" DataValueField="datacolumn"
    SelectedValues='<%# Bind("Items") %>' />
```

**Where SelectedValues attribute is of type `NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<string>`**

How can I transform it into a GridView with same binding functionality?

```
<GridView runat="server" ID="ItemsAllowed" ShowFooter="false" DataSourceID="ItemsData"
 AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserAllowed">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="cbUserAllowed" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ItemList">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Literal ID="litItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("datacolumn") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</GridView>
```

I need to transform it to a GridView cause I need to add one extra checkbox column.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to do the two-way DataBinding manually.

Binding from DataSource on OnRowDataBound event handler.

And binding to DataSource in the parent's control OnRowEditing event handler.

Example: [ASP.NET data bind two-way, bi-directional from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871404/asp-net-data-bind-two-way-bi-directional-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have did is correct but you need to add the "Checked" attribute to the checkbox to call a server side function to check if the current checkbox is in the selected items.

Comment: how do i do that? the binding must be two way

Comment: Is there a column in the returned data that specify if the checkbox is checked or not ?!

Comment: SelectedValues is of type NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<string>. Inside it there are strings for the labels which are checked. The CustomCheckBoxList is inside a FormView which is also databound, SelectedValues='<%# Bind("Items") %>' being done on the parent's field 'Items'.

Comment: If you want to allow bidirectional binding, you have to make the returned data for the grid contains a column with the value checked or not checked so that we can call the "Bind" function on it.