# Setting Value of Bind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

In my code I have this bind set up to a textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CompanyTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Company") %>' CssClass="txtbox" />
```

Is there a way a way to access the "Company" value and change it programmatically, or do I simply change the value of the textbox and It will update accordingly?

Comment: Where are you trying to access this value? On the server (vb.net code) or on the client (javascript)?

Comment: I'm trying to set it, in javascript

Comment: Are you just trying to set the value of the textbox? If you set it in JavaScript, then it will be sent to the server when the form posts.

Comment: I want to be able to set the value, without breaking the bind.  I have a combobox that on change will update the value of the CompanyTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Check links below:

http://mrbool.com/two-way-data-binding-course-asp-net-4-and-visual-studio-2010-part-46/22435

http://www.ccopus.com/blog/article.asp?id=24

You can see the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871404/asp-net-data-bind-two-way-bi-directional-from-code-behind)